# Recommend a differentiable transform from $\mathbb R ^ n$ to $n$ ordered partition boundaries of $(0,1)$

Tags: transformation, set-partition

I am looking for a differentiable transform that, given numbers in $\mathbb R ^ n$, calculates $n$ partition boundaries of $(0,1)$, in either increasing or decreasing order.

For example, for $n=1$, we can use $\sigma(x_1)$ as the boundary, where $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function.

For $n>1$, I was thinking of multiplying sigmoids together. So the partition boundaries would be $\sigma(x_1), \sigma(x_1)\sigma(x_2), \sigma(x_1)\sigma(x_2)\sigma(x_3), \ldots$ which would always be in a decreasing order.

Do you have any alternative recommendations for how to go about creating the partition boundaries?

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with $n$ subintervals, rather than $n$ boundaries, you could create partitions according to the [softmax function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). More specifically, you could partition the interval at
$$
\frac{e^{x_1}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\cdots+e^{x_n}},\\
\frac{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\cdots+e^{x_n}},\\
\vdots\\
\frac{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\cdots +e^{x_{n-1}}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\cdots+e^{x_n}}
$$
This would make the width of the $k$th interval equal to $\frac{e^{x_k}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\cdots+e^{x_n}}$

Comment: After getting $n$ subintervals $(0, x_1), (x_1, x_2), \ldots, (x_{n-1}, 1)$, we can get $n$ boundaries $x_1/2, (x_1 + x_2) /2, \ldots, (x_{n-1} + 1)/2$.